# Three.js application automation using cypress

Tags: three.js, ui-automation, e2e-testing

Is there any way to write e2e tests for three.js application using cypress?

I have tried three-musketeers package (https://github.com/webgl/three-musketeers) but facing challenging to retrieve the existing scene.

And also have come across puppeteer package but then its not helpful in this scenario.

Thanks and appreciate the help!